# Android: Network call made with RxJava and OkHttp SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, okhttp, socket-timeout-exception

I have a simple API request which I make by using Retrofit/OkHttp.

```
private fun getNext(
        nextId: Long
    ): Observable<NextData> =
        userRepo.getNext(nextId)
            .map { it.toDomainObject() }
```

The API replies `200, OK` and it replies fast (definitely less than 3 seconds). However, this call sometimes throws

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
```

I also configured my `OkHttpClient` to have `callTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. I really do not understand why I have such an exception. Any ideas about solving this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in Kotlin but maybe this will help you.
I had same problem and this helped me in Java:

```
client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    client.setWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```